# Insert data from mysql to cli listbox

Tags: mysql, .net, winforms

[listbox is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsogK.png)I want to take data from my sql and insert it into my listbox form but i can't. By compiling listbox is empty. What do i wrong?

```
private: System::Void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
        {
            String^ SQLconnection = "Server = localehost; Uid = root; Password = pass123; Database = details";
            MySqlConnection^ conn = gcnew MySqlConnection(SQLconnection);
            MySqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM details.material;", conn);
            MySqlDataReader^ reader;

        try
        {
            conn->Open();
            reader = cmd->ExecuteReader();
            while (reader->Read())
            {
                listBox1->Text +=(reader->GetInt32(0));
            }


        }catch (Exception^ ex)
        {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }

        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what is the error message. In any case what is  _localehost_? did you mean _localhost_? Also remove all those whitespaces in the connectionstring before and after =

Comment: @Steve omg didn't even notice, thanks. yes i mean localhost. I did corrected it. it don't give any errors. this code in theory must take data from mysql and insert it in my listbox. but when i compile it my listbox is empty.

Comment: does the connection open ?